# Working with the option -x in zip

Tags: zip

I can't manage to figure out the `-x` option in the command zip.
I want to compress a working folder to save it as a backup, but I have some files and a directory that contains huge files that I don't need to save.
Therefore I would like to compress the whole directory except for the one listed above.

Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
echo "Saving all work directory in the backup"

now=$(date +'%Y_%m_%d')
filename=($(echo "backup_"$now))
cd /local00/home/F48174/Documents/scripts_eprou_aster/
echo "... removing /base because it's huge ..."

zip -9 -r /local00/home/F48174/Documents/backup/$filename.zip  -x /local00/home/F48174/Documents/scripts_eprou_aster/base/
```

Comment: You need to tell `zip` what has to be zipped: `zip -r archive.zip folder_to_zip -x file_not_to_zip`

Answer (score 0):

Modify the last line to be,

```
zip -9 -r /local00/home/F48174/Documents/backup/$filename.zip  -x /local00/home/F48174/Documents/scripts_eprou_aster/base\*
```